# How to get the child of a static div to appear in front of the child of a later static div? Z-index stacking context

Tags: html, css

This seems like it should be an old problem with a well known solution. Maybe it's a testimony to the poverty of my search-engine skills or the crudity of the search engines, but I can't seem to find a solution online.

You can look at my simplified setup is you run the code snippet. I've got two divs (light blue), one above the other. Each has a custom pull-down menu widget (yellow) activated by clicking a chevron (pink/salmon). But when I activate the menu of the top item, the chevron of the bottom item appears *in front of* the menu no matter what I do with the z-indexes. How do I get the chevron to appear *in back of* the pull-down menu? In other words, how to I get the menu to appear in front of the parent divs including in front of their chevrons?

If I put a z-index on the chevron div, nothing changes. If I get rid of the z-index on `.baseItem .action` or on the menu, the menu goes *behind* the blue parent divs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Z-index stacking experiment</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      li.baseItem {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      border: 1px solid #888;
      background-color: #cce;
      }
      .baseItem .action {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 5px;
      z-index: 1;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
      .chevron {
      background-color: #f88;
      }
      .chevron:before {
      content: '^';
      }
      ul.ui-menu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0.5em;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      white-space: nowrap;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      border: 1px solid #61605e;
      background-color: #ff0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<ul>
<li class="baseItem">
  <div>Parent 1, line 1</div>
  <div>Parent 1, line 2</div>
  <div class="right action">
    <span class="chevron"></span>
    <ul class="ui-menu" style="display: block;">
      <li><div><span>Edit</span></div></li>
      <li><div><span>Duplicate</span></div></li>
      <li><div><span>Delete</span></div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="baseItem">
  <div>Parent 2, line 1</div>
  <div>Parent 2, line 2</div>
  <div class="right action">
    <span class="chevron"></span>
    <ul class="ui-menu" style="display: none;">
      <li><div><span>Edit</span></div></li>
      <li><div><span>Duplicate</span></div></li>
      <li><div><span>Delete</span></div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.action` is already positioned absolutely so `z-index` will reorder children within the element. You need to get rid of the absolute positioning on `.action` so that it "lies flat" with its parent div, and doesn't stick up above the menu.

So you need a design that gets rid of `position: absolute` on `.action`. Here as an example I've used `grid`:

```css
.baseItem {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background-color: #cce;
}

.action {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
}

.action::before {
  content: '^';
  background-color: #f88;
}

.ui-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 1px solid #61605e;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="baseItem">
    <div>Parent 1, line 1</div>
    <div>Parent 1, line 2</div>
    <div class="right action">

      <ul class="ui-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li>
          <div><span>Edit</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><span>Duplicate</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><span>Delete</span></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="baseItem">
    <div>Parent 2, line 1</div>
    <div>Parent 2, line 2</div>
    <div class="right action">

      <ul class="ui-menu" style="display: none;">
        <li>
          <div><span>Edit</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><span>Duplicate</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><span>Delete</span></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you explain what `grid` is doing? I mean: what's the advantage of using it here?

Comment: I use `display: grid` on `.baseItem` elements so I don't need to use `position: absolute` on `.action` elements. This ways `.ui-menu` elements with `position: absolute` are positioned over every chevrons

Comment: Cedric, thanks again! I added a little to your answer, based on what you just said. I'm still curious about how exactly something with z-index of 1 appears above something with z-index of 10.

Comment: @JohnK an element with `z-index: 1` appears above an element with `z-index: 10` when both parents are positioned and the parent of the first element (with `z-index: 1`) is already over the parent of the second element (with `z-index: 10`)

Answer (score 1):

`ul.ui-menu` does not need to be absolutely positioned or have a z-index because the parent `.baseItem .action` is already `position: absolute`

```
ul.ui-menu {
      white-space: nowrap;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      border: 1px solid #61605e;
      }
```

I don't know how you are handling the opening and closing of your menus here, but I would recommend adding `z-index: 1` to whichever `.baseItem .action` is opening. Perhaps by adding an `.active` class.

(Side note: `transform: translateY(-50%)` and `top: 50%` on `.baseItem .action` may not be necessary. Try `top: 0`.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The menu is positioned absolutely so that it has the correct position with respect to its `.action` parent. `.action` is opening the menu. What are you suggesting I replace it with? Also for future reference, the 50% in `translateY(-50%)` moves the element half of the height of the element itself, while `top: 50%` moves the element half of its parent's height. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the position in the Z plane using transform: translateZ

```css
* {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

li.baseItem {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background-color: #cce;
}

.baseItem .action {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.chevron {
  background-color: #f88;
}

.chevron:before {
  content: '^';
}

ul.ui-menu {
  transform: translateZ(10px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 1px solid #61605e;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="baseItem">
    <div>Parent 1, line 1</div>
    <div>Parent 1, line 2</div>
    <div class="right action">
      <span class="chevron"></span>
      <ul class="ui-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li>
          <div><span>Edit</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><span>Duplicate</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><span>Delete</span></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="baseItem">
    <div>Parent 2, line 1</div>
    <div>Parent 2, line 2</div>
    <div class="right action">
      <span class="chevron"></span>
      <ul class="ui-menu" style="display: none;">
        <li>
          <div><span>Edit</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><span>Duplicate</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><span>Delete</span></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your solution seems to get the job done. I'm wondering if there's anyway I can avoid `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on all elements. The app I'm working on is not small, and I'd rather avoid changing the style of every element in it, since doing so might have side effects in a place I don't notice readily.

Comment: You only need to set it on the elements involved in the tree that goes to your element. Also, this is handled by the GPU instead of the CPU, and usually the GPU are highly efficient handling the z-order. Anyway, the best way to know if it is performant is to try it. I guess that even the brute force solution that I gave would work fairly well

Comment: Thanks again, @vals. I'm not worried about performance so much as changing other parts of the site, or at least constraining future design decisions.